# Laravel bootstrap 5 position header navbar position problem, can't position certain element into top-right

Tags: html, css, laravel, navbar, bootstrap-5

I want to create a top navbar that have project name and menu on the left and user management on the right but what I got was both of them on the left like this: [top navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7RAe.png)

I put this navbar on header this is the code, this is on dashNavbar.blade.php:

```
<header>
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <button class="btn btn-dark" id="button-toggle">
            <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
          </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Perpustakaan Perkantas</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        
      </ul>
<!-- right navbar links -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->username }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</header>
```

what I want is somewhat similar to regular ui auth bootstrap like this just different color and what item in it:[top navbar normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL0V5.png)

here's code of original code in app.blade.php for comparison:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            @if (Route::has('login'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif

                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried placing your link inside `<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">...</ul>` where the left side navigation should be placed?

Comment: there's me-auto before ms-auto... it's kind of blank as of now.

Comment: Not sure what that's supposed to mean, but yes, that's where the left-side navigation goes in [Bootstrap 5 navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#how-it-works) (ms-auto=left, me-auto=right)

Comment: Welp... I tried fill the left with link and also tried switch the code... still aren't changing, all of them on the left.

Comment: I uh... accidentally found unusual solution.... just adding justify-content-end class in <div> before <ul> , it is a bit odd however that ms-auto and me-auto works on in-built auth that placed navbar on body or at least after app class. but if it's header it's fails?

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS attached to test what you have.

I think you might need to wrap all the items that need to be on the left side in a div as you did for the items that have to be on the right. The result will be two divs in the nav element. The right side div styled using flex, and the items are placed at the end.

```
<nav>
  <div class="left"> all items for left side </div>
  <div class="right"> all items for right side and place me at the end </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: OP is using Bootstrap5. Their [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/) docu

Comment: I kinda using css for menu/sidebar part... but some I kinda need top-navbar of bootstrap5... as of now I don't know where's the problem.

Comment: Have you been able to apply the suggestion above?

Comment: found unusual solution that almost kinda like suggestion above but with justify-content-end. class with just direction doesn't work.